# Immersion of $(RP)^2$ in $R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am working on the following problem..
Let g: $S^2$-->$R^3$ be a map given by the formula g(x,y,z)=(yz,xz,xy), which induces in a natural way a mapping $G$ from $RP^2$ into $R^3$. I need to find six points of the real projective plane $p_i$ i=1,...,6 such that G is an immersion for all the other points in $RP^2$. However my calculations show that we do not need to deduct those points for $G$ to be an immersion. I am propably missing something here, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should write down explicitly the differentials here; if I'm not mistaken the points of $S^2$ that look like $(1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2, 0)$ and various look alikes have noninjective differentials

Comment: @Max Thanks for your answer, you are correct !! I made a childish mistake while calculating the Jacobian Matrix in a coordinate system. I calculated the rank of the (correct) Jacobian in each coordinate chart and the points which eliminate all determinants of 2x2 submatrixes are exactly the one you mention and I am looking for.